# Magento 2.3 when Product export gets “Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon" Not able to see export file in grid

Tags: magento2, importexport

When i tried to export the product from admin of Magento 2.3.2, i am not able to see the exported csv in below grid

[image: export]

Answer (score 1):

In new version of Magento, export option was moved to queue

if you want to start this services then we have to run the services.
use below cmd to start the services

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

if you want to run in background then append & that is

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor &
```